# Group By and Join (DB2)

Tags: sql, join, group-by, db2

I have a little problem with an SQL-Statement right now. I need to somehow get a group by condition inside of a Join. Well now I do know that this doesn't work, but there most be a way to do this and I hope  you guys can give me a clue on how to do this.

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   btst.Ordnungsbegriff AS BBNR,
   COUNT(vp.KVNR) 
   FROM T_Betriebsstaette btst
      JOIN T_VERSICHERUNGSZEIT vz
         ON vz.BETRIEBSNUMMER = btst.Ordnungsbegriff
         AND vz.VALIDTO = date('2999-12-31')
         AND vz.PERSONENKREIS = 'Beschäftigte'
         AND vz.BEITRAGSGRUPPEKV_IID > 0
         AND vz.PERSONENGRUPPENSCHLUESSEL IN (101, 102, 103, 118, 119)
         JOIN T_VERSICHERTEPERSON vp
            ON vp.OID = vz.VERSPERS_VERSPERSON_ID
            AND ('1' = '0' or '1' = '1' and (vp.VIPKENNZEICHEN is null or  NOT vp.VIPKENNZEICHEN is null and vp.VIPKENNZEICHEN  NOT  in (5, 6)))
```

The Group By Clause I have to get in there:

```
GROUP BY vz."VALIDTO", vz."BETRIEBSNUMMER"
```

I'm not really an expert in SQL. Hope you guys can help me out a little. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `group by` clause, any element in the `select` clause must either be in the `group by` clause, or an aggregate function (sum, max, etc)

So

```
SELECT 
   btst.Ordnungsbegriff AS BBNR,
   COUNT(vp.KVNR) 
   FROM 

   ...
GROUP BY vz."VALIDTO", vz."BETRIEBSNUMMER", btst.Ordnungsbegriff
```

Comment: Ok, now I feel kinda stupid. Thanks anyways. You helped me out a lot. :)